# Does a payment processor/gateway exist that enables a global marketplace with a shopping cart, before scaling?

Tags: javascript, paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, marketplace

I asked this question a different way and it was immediately closed. Trying again. I've searched exhaustively and cannot find a payment processor that supports the ability to implement a global marketplace where the platform/marketplace is in the US and sellers are in other countries (something similar to Etsy). Specifically, one that can be implemented before a web application is handling a large volume of sales (so something that can be used in an early stage startup for example).

And where the platform can offer a shopping cart where the the buyer can fill with products from both US and international sellers, and pay for everything with one payment (again similar to Etsy, Amazon, etc).

Do any such payment processors exist?

Comment: Additional context on research done: These payment processors do not offer solutions for this scenario: Stripe, Adyen, Paypal, Braintree, Wepay and many others I've researched in-depth and contacted. If anyone has successfully implemented a payment processor it would be awesome to learn which company and approach you found that supports this.

Comment: What is the issue with those providers before you are handling large volumes of sales? Is it possible that people like Etsy got around this by not being global before they had a large volume of sales

Comment: The issue is companies/payment services like Adyen, Paypal Commerce Platform, etc provide this type of global functionality, but won't work with startups that aren't already doing big numbers. You're right about the possibility of starting out as a US only platform initially for example, then switching to a global provider after scaling. The issue is making tons of sellers go through a cumbersome identity verification and sign-up process again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Stripe's Standard Connect would fit your needs: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts

Comment: Unfortunately Stripe Connect with Standard accounts, or any other type of connected account does not support this. I've edited my question to clarify a bit, but I'm looking for Etsy/Amazon type functionality. So, a platform with a shopping cart where sellers from multiple countries can sell products. A buyer can add multiple products, possibly from different countries, and pay for everything with one payment.